# Getting Random number from 0 to 1000 daily iOS

Tags: ios, random

I have a code to generate random numbers from 0 to 1000, its is the following

```
 int randomValue = (random() % 1000);
```

I want the app to generate it daily in a specific time for example at 10:00 am.

How can I do that??

Comment: Your question has nothing at all to do with random numbers. Your question is about how to perform some action at a fixed time daily. Do some searching on that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+perform+action+specified+time

Comment: to be clear, I want the app generate random number daily to retrieve a content from sqlite database daily, every day a new data

Comment: Right. As I said, your question is all about how to perform a daily action at a given time. You already know how to do the other parts.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I can't find how to perform it at the specific time daily. :S

Comment: I would say use Parse and pay and then setup a bunch of remote notifications when the user first uses the app and have it trigger the random number.  If you only want it to happen once and don't care when just save a NSDate object and check when ever the app becomes active if it has been over 24 hours re run the randomValue method.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to answer : don't do that, you have an iDevice, not a 24/24 7/7 server. But perform this on a server side, and when required, ask your server for the values...